# If $\lim\limits _{x\to\infty}\left(\log f\right)'\left(x\right)$ is negative, then $\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)dx $ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$   be a positive differentiable function, and suppose that $\lim\limits _{x\to\infty}\left(\log f\right)'\left(x\right)$   exists is negative. Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)dx  $ converges.

By differentiating $$\left(\log f\right)'\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{1}{f}\cdot f'\right)\left(x\right)=\frac{f'\left(x\right)}{f\left(x\right)}$$
All I was able to show is that $f$ is bounded and goes to $0$, and that $f'(x)$ is always negative (after some point). I know I can find some bound on $f'(x)$ as well, but wasn't able to figure out any way of using it.

any hints?

Comment: Hint: If $f'\leqslant -cf$, what can you deduce about $f$?

Comment: @Did Thinking about it so far, still not sure.. Definitely feels like I'm missing something simple though..

Comment: Thus, $f'+cf\leqslant0$. Can you transform the LHS into nearly the derivative of a function? Perhaps remember how you would solve $f'+cf=g$ for some given function $g$.

Comment: @Did I didn't really understand your second comment though, but I did take the first one somewhere, and I'd love to know if my answer is correct :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we will notice that by the chain rule we get:

$$ \left(\log f\right)'\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{1}{f}\cdot f'\right)\left(x\right)=\frac{f'\left(x\right)}{f\left(x\right)} $$

now suppose $\lim\limits _{x\to\infty}\left(\log f\right)'\left(x\right)=-L<0$, then we can find $x_{0}$ such that for $x>x_{0}$, $$\frac{f'\left(x\right)}{f\left(x\right)}<-\frac{L}{2}$$

or $$-f'\left(x\right)>\frac{L}{2}f\left(x\right)$$

This in turn shows that for any fixed $n>x_{0}$
$$\int_{0}^{n}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{x_{0}}f\left(x\right)dx+\frac{2}{L}\int_{x_{0}}^{n}\frac{L}{2}f\left(x\right)dx
$$
$$\leq\int_{0}^{x_{0}}f\left(x\right)dx+\frac{2}{L}\int_{x_{0}}^{n}-f'\left(x\right)dx$$

then

$$\int_{0}^{x_{0}}f\left(x\right)dx+\frac{2}{L}\int_{x_{0}}^{n}-f'\left(x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{x_{0}}f\left(x\right)dx-\frac{2}{L}f\left(x\right)\bigg|_{x_{0}}^{n}$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{x_{0}}f\left(x\right)dx-\frac{2}{L}f\left(x\right)\bigg|_{x_{0}}^{n}=\int_{0}^{x_{0}}f\left(x\right)dx-\frac{2}{L}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(n\right)-f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)$$

which converges if and only if $\lim\limits _{n\to\infty}f\left(n\right)$ converges, but as for $x>x_{0}$, $\frac{f'\left(x\right)}{f\left(x\right)}<0$, and as $f\left(x\right)>0$, it must be that $f'\left(x\right)<0$. This shows both that $f\left(x\right)$
  is decreasing and bounded by $0$. Then it must converge, completing the proof.

Comment: Not the quickest way, but it works, +1. The trick worth to remember is that $f'+cf\leqslant0$ is equivalent to $g'\leqslant0$ for $g(x)=e^{cx}f(x)$, hence $g$ is nonnegative and nonincreasing for $x$ large enough, that is, $g(x)\leqslant g(x_0)=K$ for every $x\geqslant x_0$, hence $f(x)\leqslant Ke^{-cx}$ for every $x\geqslant x_0$, which implies the desired integrability.

Comment: Note finally that the "trick" I described above is not really a trick but more of a method, since $f'+cf\leqslant0$ is equivalent to $f'+cf=h$ with $h\leqslant0$ and solving $f'+cf=h$ allows to write explicitely $f$ in terms of $h$, then the rest follows.